# rails, multiple instances of a resource edited togheter, the RESTful way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

In my application I have a very RESTful resource called Customer. 
But each Customer has a group of resources bounded to it in a fixed way, that are: shipping_address, company_address, warehouse_address. 
The resource from a database or REST point of view is the Address, and at the db level I have an address with a field called type with 'shipment', 'company', 'warehouse' values in it. 
But they are represented on the same web page, something like company/id/adresses. 
How can I manage this yet trying to enforce the RESTful orientation of rails?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, this would work:

```
# models/customer.rb
class Customer < ...
  belongs_to :shipping_address, class_name: 'Address'
  belongs_to :company_address, class_name: 'Address'
  belongs_to :warehouse_address, class_name: 'Address'
end

# models/address.rb
class Address < ...
  has_many :shipping_customers, foreign_key: 'shipping_address_id', class_name: 'Customer'
  has_many :company_customers, foreign_key: 'company_address_id', class_name: 'Customer'
  has_many :warehouse_customers, foreign_key: 'warehouse_address_id', class_name: 'Customer'
end
```

Here is an edited sample run on the rails console to set this up and verify it within an existing app:

```
$ rails g model Customer name:string shipping_address_id:integer company_address_id:integer 
$ rails g model Address details:string address_type:string
$ bin/rake db:migrate
$ rails c
...(Rails 4.1.5)
irb(main):001:0> @company_address = Address.create! details: 'company address', address_type: 'company'
=> #<Address id: 1, details: "company address", address_type: "company">
irb(main):002:0> @shipping_address = Address.create! details: 'shipping address', address_type: 'shipping'
=> #<Address id: 2, details: "shipping address", address_type: "shipping">
irb(main):003:0> Customer.create! name: 'some customer', shipping_address: @shipping_address, company_address: @company_address
=> #<Customer id: 1, name: "some customer", shipping_address_id: 2, company_address_id: 1>
irb(main):004:0> Customer.first.shipping_address
=> #<Address id: 2, details: "shipping address", address_type: "shipping">
irb(main):005:0> Customer.first.company_address
=> #<Address id: 1, details: "company address", address_type: "company">
```

If necessary, you could validate that an address has the right address_type before using it for a certain customer.

Comment: yes, thanks for the idea about the database structure, i'm trying it. but REST has more to do with how resources are presented to a client as URLs. How would you present the Addresses of a Customer from the URL point of view?